# azure webapp - write html form action using "post" method cannot pass data

Tags: html, azure, azure-web-app-service

i am writing a html form action to do a login function, but in my website, it can't pass and do any action on it, there are following code:

```
<form action ="/signup/AI.php" method="post">
            <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-20" data-validate="Enter ID">
                <input class="input100" type="text" name="username" placeholder="ID">
                <span class="focus-input100"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-25" data-validate = "Enter password">
                <input class="input100" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="password">
                <span class="focus-input100"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
                <button class="login100-form-btn" type="submit">
                    Sign In
                </button>
```

and the following result:

[highlight will show input data here and cannot go other page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIFea.jpg)

i think this code no problem because i have try in local server and it's work.
please help me thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you please show more details? It would be better if you could share a sample on GitHub for us to test. @Kutmei Ku

Comment: @DorisLv https://github.com/kutmei009/testing.git
there is a form action file, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your test sample, there are two guesses might help.

1. **It might be resources lost or data had not passed successfully.** Press **F12** to check if the user name and password value had been got or not. You could also see if the redirected page or other related resources lost or not.
2. **It might be the database's fault.** As I can see, your project is connected to a local Database, you should migrate it to cloud database before deploying to Azure.

Comment: solved, it not passed data to path and i have find it and fix it, thanks a lot